# Change width on slideshow for Shopify New Standard theme

Tags: jquery, slideshow, shopify

I'm wanting to modify the New Standard theme for Shopify and have managed to change all of the css to 960px width and the JS relating to the slideshow (var **container_width = 960;**). There's something else I'm clearly missing here that is cropping the images themselves to 884px on upload.

Any idea what other files or changes need to be made to stop the images from being cropped to 884px and keep them 960px wide?

Answer (score 1):

In the settings.html file look for these lines:

```
 <td><label for="slide_1_image">Background Image</label></td>
 <td><input type="file" name="slide_1.jpg"  data-max-width="884" /></td>
```

you need to modify the data-max-width to the desired width.
Repeat the same step for all the image upload fields.